# Hide MasterView in UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

**UPDATE**

I ended up fixing the issues with MGSplitViewController, so I am now using this fork of the project: http://github.com/ArtSabintsev/MGSplitViewController At the time of writing this edit, the fork hasn't been pulled into Matt Gemmell's master branch.

**Please Note**

1. My iPad app is Landscape only, and is iOS5 and iOS6 compatible
2. I have a partially working solution, but I need to take it one step further.
3. For the majority of the screens in my app, I need to present both the master and detail views (normal behavior).
4. At one point, I need to only the detailVC to be present.

**How am I doing it now?**

I am using the following UISpliterViewControllerDelegate Method

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return self.hideRootViewController;
}
```

where hideRootViewController is a boolean that is set to NO initially.

**The Partial Solution**

If I change the boolean to YES (in any screen/VC in my app) and rotate the screen, the masterVC disappears, and the detailVC occupies the entire screen.

**The Remaining Problem**

How do I force this change without physically having to rotate the device, or how do I force a device orientation notification change to redraw UISplitViewController?

The following attempts have **failed**:

1. CGAffineTansformation (Identity and small angle transformations)
2. Posting a UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
3. Calling setNeedsLayout on splitVC.view
4. Presenting and immediately dismissing modalVC's on splitVC

Note: I am not using MGSplitViewController, nor do I want to use that class in this project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why dont you use [mgsplitviewcontroller](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/). I used it in my project, it works wonderful and very easy implement. You can able hide/switch master view easily.

Comment: Because it doesn't work with landscape-only iOS 6 projects (at least it looked broken in my tests). I don't feel like altering a project of that caliber. I may checkout some of the forks.

Comment: What do you mean it looked broken? Graphic?

Comment: The views weren't displaying properly in the test project MG provides.

Comment: I dont have iOS 6 installed. I will get back you after I'm done with install.

Comment: Mean while upgrade my xcode, i found this. Some ppl claimed it fix by modifying little code (but I dont have ability to confirm this). Here is the link: https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/issues/69

Comment: Interesteting, I got the MGSplitVC example project working with that discussion. You have to change self.window.rootViewController = splitVC - Then I added the layoutSubviews message in viewDidAppear

Comment: I'm still downloading:( So I need to update my code in my project too. If it help to solve your problem, please accept my answer.

Comment: Yup, I just got it working. Will mark you answer correct after a couple more tests

Comment: Marked your answer as correct. Here's the fix: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/MGSplitViewController

I also made a pull request for it, so hopefully, @matt-legend-gemmell

Comment: Thanks I will pull from there then.

Answer (score 0):

To manually force a rotation, you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:]
```